# Are 2 consecutive statements sequenced-before each other?

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, x86, stdatomic

I'm reading a part of the C Standard related to multi-threaded execution and highly confused by the definition of *Sequenced-before* which is used to define *inter-thread happens before*:

`5.1.2.4/16`:

`A` is *inter-thread happens before* `B` if for some action `X`

> `A` is sequenced before `X` and `X` inter-thread happens before `B`

---

Initially I was thinking that if action `A` precedes action `B` in the program order then `A` sequenced before `B`, but consider the following simple example:

```
int read_write(int *a, int *b) {
    *a = 10;
    return *b;
}
```

which compiles to

```
read_write:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 10
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        ret
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jnqeY6fdq)

It's clear that if `*a`, and `*b` are unrelated memory locations then according to `Intel Manual Vol.3`:

- `store` can be reordered with later `load` to unrelated memory location

It's clear that such reordering happens on the hardware level due to store-buffer forwarding, but the Standard makes it clear that Sequenced-before is about how exactly evaluations are done:

`5.1.2.3/3`:

> Sequenced before is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation
> between evaluations executed by a single thread, which induces a
> partial order among those evaluations. Given any two evaluations A and
> B, if A is sequenced before B, then the execution of A shall precede
> the execution of B. (Conversely, if A is sequenced before B, then B is
> sequenced after A.) If A is not sequenced before or after B, then A
> and B are unsequenced.

Which in the example is unspecified. So this means that the store `*a = 10;` is **unsequenced** to the load `*b`. The Standard notes at `5.1.2.3/6` that

> Volatile accesses to objects are evaluated strictly according to the
> rules of the abstract machine.

---

***QUESTION:*** Is it sufficient to make at least one pointer to point to a `volatile` variable, or both `int *a` and `int *b` must be `volatile` to ensure sequenced-before realtion?

Here is what I mean:

```
int read_write(volatile int *a, int *b) {
    *a = 10; 
    //sequenced before since a points to volatile int
    return *b;
}
```

and

```
int read_write(int *a, volatile int *b) {
    *a = 10; 
    //sequenced before since b points to volatile int
    return *b;
}
```

But adding `volatile` does not change the compiled code which is relatively confusing.

Comment: Re: the title: Yes sequenced-before but not inter-thread sequenced-before.  Also, concurrent read of `*a` (for non-atomic `int *a`) would be data-race UB.  In ISO C11, no, `volatile` is useless for this.  In practice on real machines, like all that GCC supports, `volatile int` is like `atomic` `relaxed` (so still no StoreLoad ordering), where `int` fits in one register (not AVR).  ([When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) - only use volatile if you're rolling your own atomics))

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I was confused by what "access" means from the Standard standpoint. It seems to be unrelated to a particular hardware implementation when it comes to sequenced-before definition.

Comment: Neither the sequenced-before nor the happens-before ordering needs to correspond to the order of execution nor of global visibility on the actual machine.  It just provides constraints on which accesses can observe each other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Which in the example is unspecified.

No, sequencing is not unspecified in your example. C 2018 6.8 4 says:

> A *full expression* is an expression that is not part of another expression, nor part of a declarator or abstract declarator… There is a sequence point between the evaluation of a full expression and the evaluation of the next full expression to be evaluated.

In the example code:

```
    *a = 10;
    return *b;
```

`*a = 10` is an expression that is not part of another expression, so it is a full expression. And `*b` is also an expression that is not part of another expression, so it is a full expression. So there is a sequence point between these two expressions.

5.1.2.3 3 says:

> … The presence of a *sequence point* between the evaluation of expressions *A* and *B* implies that every value computation and side effect associated with *A* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with *B*…

So the value computations and the side effect of `*a = 10` are sequenced before the value computation of `*b`.

> … according to Intel Manual Vol.3:
>
> - `store` can be reordered with later `load` to unrelated memory location

This is irrelevant to C semantics. The hardware may execute the operations one way or another, but its end results will conform to the required C semantics (because the compiler was written to generate instructions that do that, even if the hardware reorders the operations).

The C semantics do not define what the hardware must do except for the *observable behavior* of the program. 5.1.2.3 6 says the observable behavior is:

> — Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.

So as long as the hardware ultimately produces the desired input and output and other behavior described above, it does not matter what order it performs operations in.

> ***QUESTION:*** Is it sufficient to make at least one pointer to point to a `volatile` variable, or both `int *a` and `int *b` must be `volatile` to ensure sequenced-before realtion?

Making `*a` or `*b` or both volatile will not change the sequencing in the C semantics, which already exists. Making both volatile will require the accesses to them to occur, as viewed outside the program, in the same order as the C semantics. Making one volatile and not the other will not require the accesses to them, as viewed outside the program, to occur in the same order as the C semantics.

What constitutes an access to a volatile object is implementation-defined. So a C implementation might define it as executing an instruction that accesses it or it might define it as the access request appearing on the memory bus or it might define it in some other way.

Comment: _Making both volatile will require the accesses to them to occur, as viewed outside the program, in the same order as the C semantics._ So the key point here is the accesses are related to the machine language itself, not a particular hardware implementation which can reorder/avoid/etc those accesses in its own way.

Comment: @St.Antario: Yes, the asm program order of `volatile` accesses is required to match C program order.  But the order of memory accesses visible to other threads can be totally different, depending on the HW.  They're like atomic `relaxed` in terms of inter-thread ordering guarantees.  (Even on x86 *not* like `acquire` and `release` because `volatile` accesses can reorder at compile-time with non-volatile accesses. 
 So you can't even count on x86's acq/rel ordering unless all shared data is `volatile`, even ones that could be plain if you were using `_Atomic` acq/rel.)

Comment: (As Eric points out, the actual definition isn't nailed down in the standard, but my previous comment describes how GCC, Clang, and MSVC `/volatile:iso` interpret it.  MSCV `/volatile:ms` gives them acquire and release semantics, going well beyond what's required by any plausible reading of the ISO standard, instead acting like (or literally exposing) x86's hardware memory model without allowing compile-time reordering of `volatile` accesses wrt. non-atomic accesses.  But it's still not seq_cst since StoreLoad reordering can still happen between volatile accesses in the same thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes I missed the fact that the presence of `Sequenced-before` by itself is not sufficient to have in _inter-thread happens before_. Some `synchronized-with` is required. Sequenced-before is inherently a single-threaded concept.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think it should also contain a reference to the "as-if rule" and explain what it is about (why it allows the compiler to completely rewrite the code, change order of operations, etc., as long as the observable behavior remains unchanged).

Comment: @mpoeter: This answer does cite the so-called “as if” rule, 5.1.2.3 6.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was referring to the paragraph "The semantic descriptions in this document define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. [...] conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.", but this is from the C++ standard and I only just realized that this question is about the C standard.